# How to create a static Go binary which runs on every distro?

Tags: linux, go

How can I create a static Go application that runs on every Linux distribution?

Is it enough just to compile Go statically as in: http://blog.hashbangbash.com/2014/04/linking-golang-statically/

Comment: Yes, If you create a static binary, it will run on every distro (with a supported kernel). I don't understand the last part, if you already have a static binary, then what are you asking?

Comment: @JimB, ignore the last bit, I just edited the question. If you can provide a sample example on how to compile a static binary in go I would be happy to accept the answer. In particular I am looking at compaling statically influxdb if that is any help.

Comment: If your want to know if it's possible to make a statically linked influxdb, you should ask that question (though it may be better to ask on an influxdb ML or forum). Depending on all the external dependencies, there may be other steps required if it's possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will work on every Linux distro if you've compiled for GOOS==linux as long as the architecture is supported (amd64/x86 etc.), and the required syscalls are available. This is usually determined by your Linux kernel version.